# How can I add blocks of markup to resource screens?

Tags: laravel-nova

I'd like to add blocks of content (markup, text etc.) to resource edit screens. This is mostly documentation to help the admin user. I want to be able to position these blocks of content - in-between individual fields, in some cases.

I'm aware of the help() method on fields. This is useful, but doesn't seem to do anything to BelongsToMany fields.

I've also been using custom cards - but as far as I know, these can only be used in the resource list, I haven't been able to add them to resource detail or edit screens.

Are there any other options or approaches out there that anyone is aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Nova offers two ways to display information on a resource view/edit screen:

[The field help text](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/fields.html#field-help-text) which you're already aware of.

[The Heading field](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/fields.html#heading-field) which allows you to create a heading which is the width of the entire form. It supports plain text and HTML. For some reason, it doesn't support rendering blade views though. Headings are supported on both the resource detail and form screens.

If you want to use a dirty hack, you could abuse a computed field to show text:

```
Text::make('', function () {
    return view('template', [])->render();
})->asHtml(),
```

and place this between the fields. Note that because it's a computed field, it isn't shown on the form screens.

So for as far I know the options are very limited.